# Date Column showing "1/1/1900 5:30 AM"

Tags: workflow, designer-workflow, custom-list, date-time, sharepoint-designer

Have created a custom list with below column

1.Title

2.Status (Drop-down column with "In progress" & "Completed")

3.In Progress Time (Date & Time Column)

4.Completed Time (Date & Time Column)

i have to capture time "In Progress Time" and "Completed Time" when status changed to "In progress" & "Completed" respectively .

For that i create a SPD workflow with two **local variable of date & time type** and fetching values in  .In Progress Time & Completed Time column .

**But in Completed Time column it shows "1/1/1900 5:30 AM"**
[image: Custom Lsst]
[image: SPD WORK FLOW]
tell me where i am doing wrong

[image]

[image]

Comment: Check variable type for Variable:Completed. Also ensure that Current Item:Modified in the else condition has correct format

Comment: Looks like `Variable:Completed` is considering the date vale you have set as invalid. Can you please check the column type and other settings?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the variable type to "String" for "Completed". I had a similar problem a while back and I remember it didnt like that having a Date and Time variable set to a date and time field. Since "Modified" is already in the format you want it sounds like, just bring it in as a String.